# How can I slice a 3D and not get a concatenated error?

Tags: slice

I am trying to slice the below 3D, but i'm getting ''Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in Untitled (line 99)
slice(X,Y,Z,[F1,V1],xslice,yslice,zslice)''

```
    [F1,V1] = isosurface(X,Y,Z,structure,0.005);
    
    %Slice the topology to view the grading/hybridization at unit cell level
    xslice = [0.5,1.5,2.5];   
    yslice = [0.5];
    zslice = [0.5];
    slice(X,Y,Z,[F1,V1],xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

Different trial and errors.